# Select Only False Data from Database using lumen

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen-5.4

I am new to coding, I'm trying to build an API using lumen. Now I have a 
   problem, I cannot find out the solution. here is my code.

```
$data = Speech::select('select * from speeches where is_requested = 0');
return response()->json(['status'=> 'Success', 'data' => $data], 200);
```

I went to find out when "is_requested" is false. Now it returns me a blank 
   array. 
   please help me if possible.{of course, it's so easy for you guys... :) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using eloquent (`$app->withEloquent();`) in your `bootstrap/app.php` file, you can do it like this :

```
<?php
$data = Speech::where('is_requested', 0)->get();
return response()->json(['status'=> 'Success', 'data' => $data], 200);
```

Without eloquent, just use the database connection like this :

```
$data = app('db')->select("SELECT * FROM speeches WHERE is_requested = ?", [0]);
```

Or if the facades are enabled :

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM speeches WHERE is_requested = ?", [0]);
```